# Show that when $f(x,y)=0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is exactly one solution for $y\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{5}y^5+y+x^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2-6x$ and show that for the equation $f(x,y)=0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a unique solution for $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

My idea:

The function $f(y)=\frac{1}{5}y^5+y+x^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2-6x$ is continious on $\mathbb{R}$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. When calculating the limits we get

$lim_{y\to\infty} f(y)= \infty$

$lim_{y\to-\infty} f(y)= -\infty$

The intermediate value theorem now states that $f(x,y)$ has at least one zero point.

The function $f(y)=\frac{1}{5}y^5+y+x^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2-6x$ can be differentiated over $\mathbb{R}$ with $f'(y)=5y^4+1$. Because for $f'(y)=5y^4+1=0$ there no solution in $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ has no extreme points. With rolls theorem it follows that there is only one zero point.

So $f$ has only one zero point. The zero of the function is the solution of the equation $f(y)=\frac{1}{5}y^5+y+x^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2-6x=0$.

It's an old analytics exam question, where I'm not really sure. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: "**If** $f(x,y)=0$, **then** for every ..." makes little sense

Comment: Apart from Hagen von Eitzen's comment, your solution is fine. You could also say that $f$ is strictly increasing in $y$, which is essentially the same as your solution.